# New column comparing dates in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am struggling to create a new column based off a simple condition comparing two dates. I have tried the following:

```
.withColumn("terms", when(col("start_date") <= col("end_date")), col("sarter_terms")).otherwise(col("exp_terms")) \
```

Which yields a syntax error.

I have also updated as follows:

```
.withColumn("terms", when(col("start_date").leq(col("end_date"))), col("sarter_terms")).otherwise(col("exp_terms")) \
```

But this yields a Python error that the Column is not callable.

How would I create a new column that dynamically adjusts based on whether the date comparator holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first statement had parenthesis mismatch , resulting in Column not callable error

```
.withColumn("terms", when(col("start_date") <= col("end_date")), col("sarter_terms")).otherwise(col("exp_terms"))
```

Change it to

```
.withColumn("terms", when(
                  col("start_date") <= col("end_date")
                , col("sarter_terms")
              ).otherwise(col("exp_terms"))
          )
```

Always Fan out the parenthesis to correctly measure the closing ones are in the appropriate places

Comment: The last suggestion is a great one, I completly missed it thanks!

Comment: PS: you don’t by any chance have a longer/code formatter for Pyspark to recommend in vscode?

Comment: Unfortunately I m not aware of this , but you can look into black - https://black.readthedocs.io/ . This might be applicable here